# Problema de recursividad dificil/imposible(?)

Tags: java, matrices, recursión

como van? como bien dice el título con olor a clickbait (xdd) tengo un problema que me dieron en la universidad que no he podido resolver a pesar de que lo he intentado por varias horas sinceramente no se me ocurre como implementar una solución :c es un problema que se basa en la **recursividad**, el problema se basa en lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*En una matriz compuesta de 1's y 0's de forma aleatoria (fijarse en la imagen) se debe transformar UNA SOLA ISLA compuesta de números "1" a una isla compuesta por números "2", teniendo en cuenta que:

UNA isla está conformada por 1's adyacentes en el sentido de los 4 puntos cardinales (arriba, abajo izquierda y derecha) como se muestra en la imagen,  las casillas marcadas en celeste conforman una isla.

En otras palabras tenemos que, por medio de un proceso (método recursivo), transformar por ejemplo las casillas (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)  (2,1) (2,2)  de **1** a **2**.

Habiendo explicado el contexto del problema procedo a mostrarles mi código paso por paso:

**1ro.-Definir una matriz y llenarla de 1's y 0's al azar:**

```
System.out.println("Ingrese filas:");
int filas = intro.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingrese columnas:");
int columnas = intro.nextInt();
int[][] matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
llenarMatriz(matriz, 2);
```

Lo que hace el trozo de código anterior es sencillamente pedir las dimensiones de la matriz y luego llenarla de 1's y 0's aleatorios con el método "llenarMatriz()", nada raro por ahora...

**2do.-Busco la isla a "colonizar" y guardo sus coordenadas para uso posterior en el MÉTODO:**

```
imprimirMatriz(matriz);  //este método solo se encarga de imprimir una matriz
                         //de forma ordenada
int guardaI = 0;
int guardaJ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
             if (matriz[i][j] == 1) {
                  guardaI = i;
                  guardaJ = j;

              }
        }
}

matriz = marcaIsla(matriz, guardaI, guardaJ);
imprimirMatriz(matriz);
```

En esta parte del código sencillamente recorremos la matriz en busca de cualquier **"1"**, ya que a partir de ESA casilla ubicaremos una isla y empezaremos a transformar todos los "1's" pertenecientes a esa isla entonces guardamos la coordenada donde encontramos ese 1 (que dada la naturaleza de mi "for" siempre será el último "1" de la matriz). 
Finalmente le asigno a la matriz el método "marcaIsla" cuyos parámetros son la misma matriz y las coordenadas donde se encuentra el "1" perteneciente a la Isla que vamos a transformar en **"2's"**.

El método "marcaIsla" es el siguiente:

```
private static int[][] marcaIsla(int[][] matriz, int guardaI, int guardaJ) { 
//ESTE MÉTODO DEBE ENCARGARSE DE CONVERTIR UNA ISLA ENTERA A SOLO 2'S


        matriz[guardaI][guardaJ] = 2;   //Convertimos la casilla principal a "2"

//Las siguientes lineas recorren las casillas adyacentes a la casilla principal con el...
//...objetivo de que si la casilla="1" entonces que la cambie por "2"

            try {
                if (matriz[(guardaI - 1)][guardaJ] == 1) { //Casilla de arriba
                    matriz[guardaI - 1][guardaJ] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI + 1][guardaJ] == 1) {// Casilla de abajo
                    matriz[guardaI + 1][guardaJ] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI][guardaJ - 1] == 1) {// Casilla izquierda
                    matriz[guardaI][guardaJ - 1] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI][guardaJ + 1] == 1) {// Casilla derecha
                    matriz[guardaI][guardaJ + 1] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        return matriz;
    }
```

Como pueden notar, al ejecutar el código efectivamente si transforma los "1" en "2" en las casillas adyacentes de la casilla de la cual sacamos las coordenadas, el proceso que realmente me complica es realizar el mismo ciclo para **TODAS** las casillas de la isla en cuestión. Se que debo aplicar el mismo proceso para las casillas que se vayan "colonizando" (cambiando de "1" a "2") pero no se como implementar la **recursividad** que permitiría realizar este proceso :c alguna idea? Desde ya, gracias por llegar hasta aquí <3

Dejo el código completo acá por si desean hacer pruebas ustedes mismos:

```
//En el main

System.out.println("Ingrese filas:");
        int filas = intro.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese columnas:");
        int columnas = intro.nextInt();
        int[][] matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
        llenarMatriz(matriz, 2);

        imprimirMatriz(matriz); 
        System.out.println("###############Separador#############");
        int guardaI = 0;
        int guardaJ = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                if (matriz[i][j] == 1) {
                    guardaI = i;
                    guardaJ = j;

                }
            }
        }

        matriz = marcaIsla(matriz, guardaI, guardaJ);
        imprimirMatriz(matriz);
```

Método imprimeMatriz():

```
public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] mat) {
       for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
               System.out.print("[ " + mat[i][j] + "\t]");
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
   }
```

Método "llenarMatriz":

```
public static void llenarMatriz(int[][] mat, int rango) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = rnum.nextInt(rango);
            }
        }
    }
```

Método "marcaIsla":

```
private static int[][] marcaIsla(int[][] matriz, int guardaI, int guardaJ) { 
        matriz[guardaI][guardaJ] = 2;
            try {
                if (matriz[(guardaI - 1)][guardaJ] == 1) {
                    matriz[guardaI - 1][guardaJ] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI + 1][guardaJ] == 1) {
                    matriz[guardaI + 1][guardaJ] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI][guardaJ - 1] == 1) {
                    matriz[guardaI][guardaJ - 1] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            try {
                if (matriz[guardaI][guardaJ + 1] == 1) {
                    matriz[guardaI][guardaJ + 1] = 2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        return matriz;
    }
```

Comment: Divide y vencerás: si tienes claro lo que es la recursividad, piensa en cuál es es caso base y los casos recursivos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente en tu código no estoy viendo uso de recursividad. Lo estas haciendo ahora de forma voraz.

Lo primero sacaría la variable `matriz` para que sea una variable de clase y no de método. Mas que nada por comodidad, ya que se usa en distintos sitios dentro de la clase.

Empezamos con tu Main:

```
private int[][] matriz; //sacamos matriz para ser accesible a todos los métodos
private int filas; //También necesitamos los limites de la matriz
private int columnas;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese filas:");
    filas = intro.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese columnas:");
    columnas = intro.nextInt();
    matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
    llenarMatriz(matriz, 2);

    imprimirMatriz(matriz); 
    System.out.println("###############Separador#############");

    //No nos hacen falta
    //int guardaI = 0;
    //int guardaJ = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            if (matriz[i][j] == 1) {
                guardaI = i;
                guardaJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
    //Ya que la matriz es accesible, no hace falta ni mandarla ni recibirla
    marcaIsla(guardaI, guardaJ);
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}
```

Ahora vamos con tu metodo `marcaIsla`

```
private static void marcaIsla(int guardaI, int guardaJ) { 

        matriz[guardaI][guardaJ] = 2;
        //con un try catch vas bien, pero si no vas a tratar la excepcion, ni lo necesitaras

        try {          
             //Nos aseguramos que miramos una coordenada dentro de los limites   
             //Procedemos a llamar al mismo método recursivamente    
            if ( guardaI-1>=0 && guardaI-1<filas && guardaJ >=0 && guardaJ<columnas && matriz[(guardaI - 1)][guardaJ] == 1) {
                marcaIsla(guardaI - 1, guardaJ);
            }
            if ( guardaI+1>=0 && guardaI+1<filas && guardaJ >=0 && guardaJ<columnas && matriz[guardaI + 1][guardaJ] == 1) {
                marcaIsla(guardaI + 1,guardaJ) = 2;
            }
            if ( guardaI>=0 && guardaI<filas && guardaJ-1 >=0 && guardaJ-1<columnas && matriz(guardaI, guardaJ - 1) == 1) {
                marcaIsla[guardaI][guardaJ - 1] = 2;
            }
            if ( guardaI>=0 && guardaI<filas && guardaJ+1 >=0 && guardaJ+1<columnas && matriz(guardaI, guardaJ + 1) == 1) {
                marcaIsla[guardaI][guardaJ + 1] = 2;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }        
}
```

Con este código te debería de ir bien. Como tu has dicho, **se va a quedar con la ultima isla**

---

Si en algún punto, el ejercicio cambia y debes de poner un `3` a la isla mas grande, entonces te tocara añadir en una lista las distintas islas que encuentres y sus dimensiones. Esto seria en el `for` de tu clase main y el metodo `marcaIsla` debe de devolver un int.